# How can I get the UIButton state to be different for each selected tableView row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

In this code I have a selected state and deselected state for my button. When the button has been pressed, it changes to green and when pressed again it changes to red to represent a deselected state.

However, all this is in a DetailViewController and when I select a particular row from my tableView then click the button to show green and go back and try a different row, the button shows green on this other row which signifies that I've pressed it(I haven't). I was wondering if there was a way to only show green for detailView of the row I selected and red for the others?

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var goingButton: UIButton!

// Actions
@IBAction func goingButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

goingButton.isSelected = !goingButton.isSelected

if goingButton.isSelected == true {
    goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingSelected"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "going")
    defaults.synchronize()
    defaults.bool(forKey: "going")
    print("defaults: \(defaults)")
} else if goingButton.isSelected == false {
    goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingDeselected"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    defaults.set(false, forKey: "going")
    defaults.synchronize()
    defaults.bool(forKey: "going")

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingDeselected"), for: UIControlState.normal)
if defaults.bool(forKey: "going")
{
    goingButton.isSelected = true
goingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "goingSelected"), for: UIControlState.selected)

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the UIButton state to be different for each tableView row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012447/how-can-i-get-the-uibutton-state-to-be-different-for-each-tableview-row)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because the button recognize the `defaults` UserDefaults property to set how self show up, when you hit the button for the first time `defaults` set to true, and when you go back the button still green (`defaults` still be true)

Try this :

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "going")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have static rows, you need a user defaults key for each row to preserve the button states between sessions. If you have a lot of rows, using Core Data will be easier and cleaner in your code.

If your rows are dynamic and you only need to save the button state for a single app session, use a dictionary that holds the row as a key and the boolean as the value. Each time you reload your table, get the state for each row's button from the dictionary.

```
var buttonStates: [Int:Bool]
```